Can the coefficient of a log become the exponent of that log's base?
While practicing logarithms, I realized the following pattern in some questions.
$$X\log_{a}b = \log_{a^{1/X}}{b}$$
In particular, I noticed I could use this to simplify certain logarithms.
To verify this, I picked two random prime numbers:
$$\log_{9}{5} = \log{5} / \log{9} \approx {0.69897000433/0.95424250943} \approx {0.73248676036}$$
$$0.5(\log_{3}{5}) = (\log{5} / \log{3^{(1/0.5)}}) = (\log{5} / \log{3^2}) = (\log{5} / \log{9}) \approx ({0.69897000433/0.95424250943}) \approx 0.73248676036$$
Another example:
$$\log_{64}{29} = \log{29} / \log{64} \approx {1.4623979979/1.80617997398} \approx {0.80966349919}$$
$$2(\log_{4096}{29}) = (\log{29} / \log{4096^{(1/2)}}) = (\log{29} / \log{64}) \approx ({1.4623979979/1.80617997398}) \approx {0.80966349919} \approx 0.80966349919$$
Upon asking my teachers, they expressed their skepticism and recommended me to not rely on this as they weren't familiar with it.
After consulting Symbolab and Mathway, both of these equations were proven true.
I tried to find reference of this, but failed to find any mention. Is this always true, or simply some odd exception?

Use \log for logarithms to get better formatting :)

Yes:$$X\log_ab = X\frac{\log b}{\log a} = \frac{\log b}{X^{-1}\log a} = \frac{\log b}{\log a^{1/X}} = \log_{a^{1/X}}b$$
Edit: looking at it in terms of powers makes it unsurprising:
$$\log_a b^X = u =  \log_{a^{1/X}}b$$
The first equation says $a^u = b^X$ and the second says $(a^{1/X})^u = a^{u/X} = b$.

You've already got a fine answer from Ramashalanka, but I'd like to add an answer that might seem a little bit more intuitive.
I like to think of "$\log_a b$" as asking the question "To what power do I need to raise $a$, in order to get $b$?". This is reflected in the fundamental property (which might sometimes be taken as a definition) of logarithms:
$$a^{\log_a b} = b.$$
With that in mind, let's look at $\log_{a^{1/X}} b$. It asks "To what power do I have to raise $a^{1/X}$ in order to get b?". Well, first you can raise it to the power of $X$, which turns $a^{1/X}$ into $a$. And then to get from $a$ to $b$, you raise the $a$ (that you just got) to the power $\log_a b$, which gets you $b$ - that's the observation we made in the first part.
So we've just shown that
$$((a^{1/X})^X)^{\log_a b} = b.$$
Now we can use the property that $(r^s)^t = r^{st}$ to rewrite the right hand side of that equation as
$$(a^{1/X})^{X\log_a b} = b.$$
So, apparently our question "To what power do I have to raise $a^{1/X}$ in order to get b?" has the answer "$X\log_a b$", i.e.
$$ \log_{a^{1/X}} b = X\log_a b.$$
I'll add that if you want to convince your teachers of the validity of your equation, and they are more impressed with equations than words, you can distill this down to computing
$$(a^{1/X})^{X\log_a b} = ((a^{1/X})^X)^{\log_a b} = (a)^{\log_a b} = b.$$
Then remind them that
$$r^s = t \iff \log_r t = s$$
and that's exactly the form of that equation, with $r=a^{1/X}$, $s = X\log_a b$, and $t=b$.

Thank you so much, especially for the time you spent helping me!

It was fun seeing how this way of thinking about logs could apply to your question, and I liked the way it came out so much that I just had to write it up!

Yes the base can have the exponent which is in multiplication with the whole log function
The only condition is that suppose x is the coefficient, then the base will have the power 1/x

Recall that $\log_b(a) = c$ means that $b^c = a$.
Now, if $9^c = 5$, then it is also true that $(9^{\frac{1}{7}})^{7c} = 5$
The first means that $\log_9(5) = c$, while the latter means that $\log_{9^{1/7}}(5) = 7c$.
So you get that $7 \cdot \log_{9}(5) = 7c =  \log_{9^{1/7}}(5)$.
